# Sphinx on server with Cpanel?

Tags: sphinx, cpanel

Had a quick question about Sphinx Search installation. Do I need to install it differently for a server with cpanel on it? Or would the normal linux installation instructions for Sphinx work just fine? I ask because I dont have a test server with cpanel, so it will be installed directly on the live server.

Comment: Do you want to manage Sphinx through cpanel? If yes, I guess it is questions to cpanel does it support Sphinx or not.

Comment: @Yaroslav Vorozhko No, I dont want to manage it via cpanel though that would be cool. Just want to make sure there isnt a different installation step for servers with cpanel on it vs just linux with no cpanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure there are no special considerations. cpanal wouldnt be used to manage sphinx, but it would work just fine. You will probably need to check the firewall, to make sure applications could contact the sphinx port.

(I've not needed to install sphinx on a cpanel server, but have used cpanel a bit. Have used sphinx with plesk - and nothing special was required there either)